# Jenkins is throwing timeout when executing more than 5 docker images at the same time

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

Basically, I have a master job, on which I run other jobs on parallel. But for some of them I am getting timeout.

```
docker run -t -d -u 1000:1000 -u root docker_image cat
17:39:17  ERROR: Timeout after 180 seconds
```

Basically, the main job groovy script looks like this:

```
node ("main"){
    stage("Stage 1") {
        catchError(buildResult: "SUCCESS", stageResult: "SUCCESS") {
            step([$class: 'WsCleanup'])
            script {
                // Other operations
                jobsToRun = [:]
                parallel jobsToRun.collectEntries { jobName ->
                    ["Running $jobName": {
                        build_job(params)
                    }]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And on other CI jobs I have this:

```
pipeline {
    agent none
    stages {
        stage("Stage 1") {
            agent {
                docker {
                    image "docker_image"
                    registryUrl "registry_url"
                    registryCredentialsId "creds1"
                    alwaysPull   true
                    args "-u root --network web"
                }
            }
            steps {
                // Other operations
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a way to prevent this timeout?